# MAX() SQL is not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

hello i have this SQL witch is supposed to give me the `max(messages.message_id)`
so i have the record where the first `message_id` is 7 and the last `message_id` is 10, but instead of giving me 10 it gives me 7... it is completely ignoring the `MAX(messages.message_id)` and giving me the first `message_id`... any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
SELECT
  profile.first_name,
  profile.last_name,
  conversations.conversation_hash,
  conversations.person_a,
  conversations.person_b,
  messages.conversation_hash,
  MAX(messages.message_id),
  messages.message,
  messages.subject,
  messages.date
FROM conversations
  INNER JOIN messages
    ON conversations.conversation_hash = messages.conversation_hash
  INNER JOIN profile
    ON profile.id = conversations.person_b
WHERE conversations.person_a = '$id'
GROUP BY messages.conversation_hash
ORDER BY messages.message_id DESC
```

tables:
conversations:

```
conversation_id | conversation_hash | person_a | person_b |
```

messages:

```
conversation_hash | from_id | to_id | message_id | subject | message | date
```

Comment: do you want to get the latest record for each conversation? or you are only interested on the `ID`?

Comment: well i want to get the latest record from each conversation

Comment: can you provide sample table with records? it is easier to build query if they were given along the question :)

Comment: Could you suply the table definitions?

Comment: try to do the max just on the table messages without the joins. Cos mybe the max record gets filtered out by the join conditions

Comment: Check if the table "messages" has the record for message_id greater than 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separately get the latest `message_id` from table `messages` inside a subquery and the result of it is then join back against the tables provided that it match on two conditions: `conversation_hash` and `message_id`.

Full Query:

```
SELECT  profile.first_name,
        profile.last_name,
        conversations.conversation_hash,
        conversations.person_a,
        conversations.person_b,
        messages.*
FROM    conversations
        INNER JOIN messages
            ON conversations.conversation_hash = messages.conversation_hash
        INNER JOIN  
        (
            SELECT  conversation_hash, MAX(message_id) max_ID
            FROM    messages
            GROUP   BY conversation_hash
        ) c ON messages.conversation_hash = c.conversation_hash AND
                messages.message_id = c.max_ID
        INNER JOIN profile
            ON profile.id=conversations.person_b
WHERE   conversations.person_a='$id'
ORDER   BY messages.message_id DESC
```

Comment: Looks just like mine -- don't think you need the ORDER BY though.

Comment: @sgeddes `ORDER BY` is optional. but looking at the OP's original query, *maybe* he still wants to *order* the result by `messages.message_id` in descending order.

Comment: Gotcha -- my assumptions were OP used that to try to get the MAX in the SQL to work.  No worries...

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
    profile.first_name,
    profile.last_name,
    conversations.conversation_hash,
    conversations.person_a,
    conversations.person_b,
    messages.conversation_hash, 
    messages.message_id,
    messages.message, 
    messages.subject, 
    messages.date
FROM conversations
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(message_id) as maxMessageId, conversation_hash 
            FROM messages
            GROUP BY conversation_hash) m 
       ON conversations.conversation_hash=m.conversation_hash
    INNER JOIN messages
        ON conversations.conversation_hash=messages.conversation_hash AND message.message_id = m.maxMessageId
    INNER JOIN profile
       ON profile.id=conversations.person_b
    WHERE conversations.person_a='$id'
```

Good luck.

Comment: sorry i tested this one, and i got a sql error, i believe something is wrong in here.

Comment: Looks like I left an "s" off of messages: "AND message.message_id = m.maxMessageId" -- good catch.